# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - Processing

Tags: java, string, exception, processing, charat

I'm trying to build a function that when given a string and a starting point will return whatever number is before the delimiter `(', ')`. So if it was handed `("45,621,9", 0)` it returns `45`.

This is what I have, and it works great until you hit the end of the string and then it throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` with `String index out of range: 8`.

So if I try with `("45,621,9", 7)`, I get that error. How can I handle the end of string and stop the loop? I thought of using a `null` check but since `char` is primitive I can't.

```
final char delim = ',';
char dataStorage;

int nextItem (String data, int startFrom) {
  String dataValue = "";
  for (int i = startFrom; i < delim; i++) {
    dataStorage = data.charAt(startFrom);
    if (dataStorage != delim) {
      dataValue = dataValue + dataStorage;
      startFrom ++;
    }
  }
  startFrom++;
  return Integer.parseInt(dataValue);
}
```

Right now if I call `nextItem("45,621,9", 7)` I get that exception when it should return `9` and then stop the loop.

Comment: Your loop condition really doesn't make sense: `for (int i = startFrom; i < delim; i++)`.  Isn't `i` mean to be the *index into the string*. Why would you compare it with the Unicode value of the delimiter you're looking for? And why are you not actually using the value of `i` within the body of the loop? Currently that's a very odd-looking loop. I suspect you should really be using substring rather than string concatenation, and that your loop should be using `for (int i = startFrom; i < data.length(); i++)` for starters.

Comment: please add tag with language name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the comment from Jon Skeet. Your for loop is not correct. Correct it like below and try:-

```
for (int i = startFrom; i < data.length(); i++){
        dataStorage = data.charAt(i);
          if(dataStorage != delim){
              dataValue = dataValue + dataStorage;
              i++;
          }
```

Comment: Please tag correctly with a java tag.